# How is it called, o for what are <%...%> this in javascript

Tags: asp.net, templates

I was searching in how to hidde a control (as a textbox,) in the client side but still use text saved in there, to access it, then I found this:

to **hide** the control

```
// javascript code

document.getElementById("<%=lblToHide.ClientID%>").style.display = "none";
```

to **show** the control

```
//javascript code

document.getElementById("<%=lblToHide.ClientID%>").style.display = "block";
```

The tutorial is from this link:
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/66995/accessing-invisible-control-in-javascript

Comment: That's not JavaScript at all. It's notation for some server-side templating system like ASP or JSP.

Comment: it's call Scriptlet. very old fashion.

Comment: please format the code for readability.

Comment: @Will thanks for your answer, it looks like Scriptlet, but then for what is the "=", is it for accessing a server or client control?

Comment: @aimme thanks for your advice, it did seem messy.

Comment: @Sergio it's used to convert the value of the expression into a string. For reference, http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaov.html